# Moving repeater in form removes serverside declaration

Tags: asp.net

I have two repeaters bound to object collections. They both work fine. But when I move repeater B to repeater A's FooterTemplate the serverside declaration of repeater B disappear.

This is not a parent/child relation.

Any ideas why this happens?

Update:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="myOuterRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
   ...
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate> 

    <asp:Repeater ID="myInnerRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button OnCommand="btnRemove_Click" ID="btnRemove" RunAt="server" />
         <%#Eval("ItemId")%>
         <%#String(Eval("Amount"))%>
     <ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> 
  </FooterTemplate>

 </asp:Repeater>
```

When I bind:

```
 myOuterRepeater.DataSource = myCollection
 myOuterRepeater.DataBind()

Dim innerRepeater As Repeater =
 myOuterRepeater.Controls(myOuterRepeater.Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("myInnerRepeater")

innerRepeater.DataSource = myInnerCollection
innerRepeater.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When nesting a control (including a second repeater) inside a repeater, it is not longer part of the page but part of the enclosing repeater.

You will need to use [`FindControl(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to get a reference to the nested repeater:

```
Repeater nested = enclosingRep.FindControl("nestedRepeaterId");
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get a nullpointerexception anymore. 

Though it does not render when I bind it.

Comment: @Henrik - without seeing your code, it will be very difficult to guess at why things happen. You need to provide a lot more detail - what is the footer markup? Where do you do the bind and can you post the code? You can edit your question and add an update to it with these details.

Comment: Solved it. I did the binding in the ItemDataBound event if ListItemType is Footer.

Thanks for the help.